# How to get varchar type input from users on my website?

Tags: 7, entities

I want to add a field to get a bank account, swift code, card no and IBAN type values from users on my Drupal 7 website.

These fields require a mix of numbers, alphabetical characters and "-".

How can I get this type of info from users?

**Note**: Core Text field is not sufficient to get varchar type input from users.

Comment: I would ask why text field would not work. Text fields are varchar in the database. Is it a length issue?

Answer (score 1):

## Use the Custom Formatters module

Consider using the [Custom Formatters](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_formatters) module, which is very easy to use and configure. And it integrates with various other modules.

Here is an excerpt from its project page:

> ... allows users to easily create custom Field Formatters without the need to write a custom module.
>
> - Pluggable editor/renderer engines:
>
>   - Formatter preset: Create simple formatters from existing formatters with preset formatter settings.
>   - HTML + Tokens: A HTML based editor with Token support.
>   - PHP: A PHP based editor with support for multiple fields and multiple values.
>   - Twig: A Twig based editor provided by the Twig filter module.
> - Supports for all fieldable entities, including but not limited to:
>
>   - Drupal core - Comment, Node, Taxonomy term and User entities.
>   - Field collection module - Field-collection item entity.
>   - Media module - Media entity.

The [Community Documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2514412) for this module seems to only be a placefholder for now (which is also where the *Read documentation* links to on the module's [Project page](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_formatters)).

However there are a few other resources about it that are worth checking out:

- [Custom Formatters for Easy Drupal Embeds](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/custom-formatters/) for a tutorial about using this module.
- Video about [What's new in Custom Formatters 7.x-2.1/2.2](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=oDEO5guc_-8).

## Create your custom module

Here are some tutorials about how to solve your question using a custom module (all for D7):

- [Create a custom field formatter in Drupal 7](http://www.whenwhowhere.com/tech-blog/create-custom-field-formatter-drupal-7)
- [Creating Custom Formatters with the Field API](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/drupal-7-tutorial-creating-custom-formatters).
- [Creating new field formatters in Drupal 7](https://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/creating-new-field-formatters-drupal-7).
- [Field API - Creating your own field formatters](http://www.grasmash.com/article/field-api-creating-your-own-field-formatters).

Comment: Sounds like a great module , I used to write my own module :D:)

Comment: Yes indeed, and with +11K reported installs, it also looks like a healthy module.